# how do I turn a jquery ui.value number into a negative value?

Tags: jquery, numerical

I have the following javascript variables...

```
var pixelTop = ui.value;
var pixelTop = (pixelTop) * (-1);
```

If I try to make the `ui.value` value negative (i'm using it in another function), it doesn't seem to work. How can I use a negative value here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var pixelTop = ui.value;
if( pixelTop > 0 )
    pixelTop *= -1;
```

Answer (score 1):

what does ui.value look like? Just a number? Or something like "58px" ?

If its just a number, it should work..

http://jsfiddle.net/wesbos/2yVDb/